# No horizontal scroll bar not showing

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Just built this site: http://www.aspenwebsites.co/

I'm still testing it in different browsers and fixing up details.

The content of the site is set in % with max and min width values also set. However, when I reduce the browser's window down below the minimum width set in my CSS - I expect to see the horizontal scroll bar, but it is not showing even if I add "overflow-x:scroll" to the HTML or BODY.

Thanks in advance for taking time for my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#contentWrap {
display: none;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: No, this is not correct, the #ContentWrap is an internal container, the above instructions add scroll bar to the #ContentWrap container, which is not right. I just want the usual Browser's scroll bar.

Comment: You are right, I also tried it before answering and I don't know why, but it showed a Horizontal Browser scroll bar. Today, I again visited the site, its working fine and now #contentWrap is edited. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: For some reason when I tried removing overflow:hidden from #contentWrap in FireBug - it didn't give the desired result. But then when I commented it out in the CSS file - now all works as it should. I only noticed that it works after reading your message and checking it out again. :)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`#contentWrap` on line 202 of style.css has overflow:hidden; property

Answer (score 0):

remove the style, overflow : hidden, it will work